# Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр класс

Tags: c#

[image: Ошибка]
На консоли абсолютно рабочий код. Перенес его на форму и сразу то ошибки, то не работает.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не вставляйте код картинкой: для вставки кода есть специальная кнопка в панели редактирования сообщения.

Comment: а что вы в форме ожидаете от `console.readline` ? перенесите код сначала нормально, глядишь  и ошибок не будет. а так `null` строка возвращается

Comment: @teran Ответы принято писать не в комментарии, а в поле ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Часть вашего рабочего кода, к сожалению, так и осталась в консоли:

```
string _cryptedString = Console.ReadLine();
```

Возьмите сию строку из какого-либо другого места, и не будете получать в следующей строке кода закономерный `NullReferenceException`

Comment: _cryptedString =null